# Three Mile Island visit

Tags: usa, sightseeing, adventure, pennsylvania

There has been some questions on tours of [Chernobyl](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6531/how-can-i-visit-chernobyl) nuclear disaster site I was wondering if the same was possible for the [Three Mile Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident) nuclear power plant?

I did find a [visitor's center](http://explorepahistory.com/attraction.php?id=1-B-260A) but no info on whether the plant itself can be visited.

Comment: A [2012 article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-10-20/the-past-is-present-at-three-mile-island-nuclear-power-plant.html) suggests tours are conducted, but note that Three Mile Island is still a functioning power station, and not a museum.

Comment: @choster Up until recently Chernobyl was a functioning power plant too but in "slightly different" juristiction.

Comment: Three Mile Island is also not a disaster site.

Comment: @KristvanBesien No.  Just a site of a nuclear reactor accident.

Comment: To be fair, you can't visit the Chernobyl plant itself either. You can get within 400m (I have the photos to prove it), but that's as close as you're permitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. It's still a functioning power plant, and as such there are safety concerns with letting people explore a place.

There is a [Three Miles Island Visitors Center](http://explorepahistory.com/attraction.php?id=1-B-260A), which has exhibits and video displays.

The company which operates the plant, Exelon, has their [Three Miles page online](http://www.exeloncorp.com/PowerPlants/threemileisland/Pages/profile.aspx) as well.

A [journalist for Bloomberg was taken on a tour](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-10-20/the-past-is-present-at-three-mile-island-nuclear-power-plant.html), however, that may have been a press tour only.  You *could* try contacting the visitors center and/or Exelon and see if there's a press tour or similar which you may be able to join.